# Dialog window reinitialisation issue

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, radio-button, createwindow

I have the following issue. In my c++ project I wanted to create a dialog window to input settings for the application to be used.
The window is created when you click in the menu: `application` -> `robot settings`.

I created the window in the following way:

```
void Robot_Settings::CreateSettingsWindow(HWND hWnd, RECT& windowSize)
{
GetWindowRect(hWnd, &windowSize);

HWND hSDlg = CreateWindowW(
    L"SettingsDialogClass",
    NULL,
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
    (windowSize.right - SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE) / 2,
    (windowSize.bottom - SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE) / 2,
    SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE,
    SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE,
    hWnd,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
}
```

then I have the window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Robot_Settings::SettingsDialogProcedure(HWND hSDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case SETTINGS_BUTTON_SAVE:
        collectInputs(hSDlg);
        break;
    case SETTINGS_BUTTON_CANCEL:
        DestroyWindow(hSDlg);
        break;
    }
case WM_CREATE:
    AddControlsToSettingsDialog(hSDlg);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    DestroyWindow(hSDlg);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProcW(hSDlg, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
}
```

And I add the inner controls on `WM_CREATE`:

```
void Robot_Settings::AddControlsToSettingsDialog(HWND hSDlg)
{
// Create Text info about amount input
CreateWindowW(
    L"Static",
    L"Input the amount of robots you want to get simulated:",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.15),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.2),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE / 2),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE / 2),
    hSDlg,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);

// Create Text info about formation input
CreateWindowW(
    L"Static",
    L"Input the formation of th robots in this format -> \"x-x-x-x\" where x is the amount of robots you want to have in each row:",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.15),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.4),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE / 2),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE / 2),
    hSDlg,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);

// Create Text info about speed input
CreateWindowW(
    L"Static",
    L"Input the speed calculated in squares per second at which you want the robots to move:",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.15),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.6),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE / 2),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE / 2),
    hSDlg,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);

// Create TextField for amount input
hAmount = CreateWindowW(
    L"Edit",
    L"",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.7),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.2),
    100,
    20,
    hSDlg,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
//formation radio buttons
CreateWindowW(
    L"BUTTON",
    L"Formation",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_GROUPBOX, 
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.7),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.35),
    120,
    120,
    hSDlg,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);

hTriangle = CreateWindowW(
    L"BUTTON",
    L"Triangle",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.72),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.4),
    100,
    20,
    hSDlg,
    (HMENU) ID_RADIO_TRIANGLE,
    NULL,
    NULL);

hRectangle = CreateWindowW(
    L"BUTTON",
    L"Rectangle",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.72),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.45),
    100,
    20,
    hSDlg,
    (HMENU) ID_RADIO_RECTANGLE,
    NULL,
    NULL);

hRhombus = CreateWindowW(
    L"BUTTON",
    L"Rhombus",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.72),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.5),
    100,
    20,
    hSDlg,
    (HMENU) ID_RADIO_RHOMBUS,
    NULL,
    NULL);

// Create TextField for speed input
hSpeed = CreateWindowW(
    L"Edit",
    L"",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.7),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.6),
    100,
    20,
    hSDlg,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
// Create button Cancel
CreateWindowW(
    L"Button",
    L"Cancel",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.7),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.8),
    100,
    40,
    hSDlg,
    (HMENU)SETTINGS_BUTTON_CANCEL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);

// Create button Save
CreateWindowW(
    L"Button",
    L"Save",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.7 - 110),
    (int)(SETTINGS_WINDOW_SIZE * 0.8),
    100,
    40,
    hSDlg,
    (HMENU)SETTINGS_BUTTON_SAVE,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
}
```

So, my issue is, that every time I try to input any text or click on the radio buttons the window seems to be reinitialized or repainted (can't figure out which is happening but it's not a normal behaviour anyway). And if you check the `rectangle` radiobutton the window closes.

You can find the entire project at:
https://github.com/JamesHawkJ/cpp/tree/master/WycieczkaRobotow

Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: `SettingsDialogProcedure` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of reaching a closing brace without executing a `return` statement.

Comment: Also, `WM_COMMAND` handling falls through to `WM_CREATE`. That's probably not what you meant.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, unrelated to your issue, since you want to create a dialog, you should call one of the [CreateDialogW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogw) family of functions (see [dialog boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588.aspx)). This allows you to author dialogs using resource (*.rc) scripts, as well as gets you keyboard navigation for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you receive a `WM_COMMAND` message from any control other than `SETTINGS_BUTTON_SAVE` or `SETTINGS_BUTTON_CANCEL`, your window procedure falls through to `WM_CREATE` case and calls `AddControlsToSettingsDialog`. You are creating more and more child windows, stacked on top of each other.

Also, `SettingsDialogProcedure` is declared to return `LRESULT`, but it may reach the closing brace without encountering a `return` statement. This exhibits undefined behavior.